# laravel remove old excel file after upload new excel file and show new data

Tags: javascript, laravel-8, laravel-excel

Here I can upload data from an excel file into the database. [image]. Now if I upload the new file into the database I want that it will remove old data and only show new data. But I don`t know how to do it. In there if I upload the new file it`s keeping old data. [image]. This is my index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 8 CRUD </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse flex-column">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <a class="btn btn-success text-light mr-5" data-toggle="medel" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModel"
                    data-attr="{{ route ('projects.create')}}" title="upload project">
                        <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                    <form action="{{ route('importProject') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="d-flex">
                        @csrf
                        <input type='file' name="file">

                        <button class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: -60px" title="Import Project">
                            <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt fa-2x"></i></button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success text-light" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal"
                    data-attr="{{ route('projects.create') }}" title="Create a project"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-lg table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">No</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col" width="30%">Introduction</th>
                <th scope="col">Location</th>
                <th scope="col">Cost</th>
                <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($projects as $project)
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">{{ ++$i }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->introduction }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->location }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->cost }}</td>
                    <td>{{ date_format($project->created_at, 'jS M Y') }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('projects.destroy', $project->id) }}" method="POST">

                            <a data-toggle="modal" id="smallButton" data-target="#smallModal"
                                data-attr="{{ route('projects.show', $project->id) }}" title="show">
                                <i class="fas fa-eye text-success  fa-lg"></i>
                            </a>

                            <a class="text-secondary" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal"
                                data-attr="{{ route('projects.edit', $project->id) }}">
                                <i class="fas fa-edit text-gray-300"></i>
                            </a>
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')

                            <button type="submit" title="delete" style="border: none; background-color:transparent;">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    {!! $projects->links() !!}


    <!-- small modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="smallModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="smallBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- medium modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="mediumBody">
                    <div>
                        <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        // display a modal (small modal)
        $(document).on('click', '#smallButton', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                // return the result
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#smallModal').modal("show");
                    $('#smallBody').html(result).show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                timeout: 8000
            })
        });

        // display a modal (medium modal)
        $(document).on('click', '#mediumButton', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                // return the result
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#mediumModal').modal("show");
                    $('#mediumBody').html(result).show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                timeout: 8000
            })
        });

    </script>

@endsection
```

This is ProjectController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Project;
use App\Imports\ProjectsImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('projects.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'introduction' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
            'cost' => 'required'
        ]);

        $projectName = $request->name;

        Project::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')
            ->with('success', $projectName. ' created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.edit', compact('project'));
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'introduction' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
            'cost' => 'required'
        ]);

        $projectName = $request->name;

        $project->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')
            ->with('success', $projectName . ' updated successfully');
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        $project->delete();

        return redirect()->route('projects.index')
            ->with('success', 'Project deleted successfully');
    }

    public function importProject()
    {
        Excel::import(new ProjectsImport, request()->file('file'));

        return back()->with('success','Project created successfully.');
    }
}
```

This is ProjectImport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Project;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;


class ProjectsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Project([
            'name'     => $row['name'],
            'introduction'    => $row['introduction'],
            'location'    => $row['location'],
            'cost'    => $row['cost']
        ]);
    }
}
```

If you need any more details you can ask me. Thank you so much for your help or Thank you so much for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking to clear the entire contents of the `projects` table with every new import, you can call the `truncate()` method on the table at the start of the import.

**WARNING: This will delete ALL existing data in the table!**
**WARNING: This will delete ALL existing data in the table!**
**WARNING: This will delete ALL existing data in the table!**

```php
class ProjectsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        Project::truncate();
    }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If this is not what you mean, please clarify the question further.